# Apple script : Duplicate file to generated folder

Tags: applescript, duplicates

I would like to run a script which copies a template file "+A3Temp.ptx" into a script generated folder on an internal Media drive. The variables for  `job_number` & `creation_date` & `client_folder` & `brand_name` & `job_name` have already been entered earlier in the script

Here is what I have, yet it keeps returning errors:

```
set media_folder to "/Volumes/Media/"
set new_folder to media_folder & job_number & creation_date & client_folder & brand_name & job_name
set destination_folder to quoted form of POSIX path of new_folder

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "/Volumes/Media/+A3Temp.ptx" to folder destination_folder
end tell
```

AS you can see, I am a newbie and in need of help.

All help Appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `POSIX file` to convert a path to a file object:

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "/usr/share/doc/bash/bashref.html" to POSIX file "/private/tmp/"
end tell
```

`POSIX path of` converts a file object or an alias to a path.

`quoted form of` escapes strings for use in shells. It surrounds text with single quotes and replaces single quotes with `'\''`, so for example `quoted form of "it's"` is `'it'\''s'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think (as I'm a newbie too) that you need to set your `new_folders` as a list, *e.g.* `set newFolder to {job_number, creation_date, media_folder, client_folder, brand_name} -- newFolders list`. now `set every folder of destinationFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of new_folder`. Not entirely sure, but that might fix your problem.

The rest of your script looks good.